# Are the rooms in "Aoi Bungaku" and "Mouryou no Hako" related or a real place?

Tags: aoi-bungaku, mouryou-no-hako

I was watching *Aoi Bungaku* episode 9 "Run, Melos" plot when I saw this scene which reminded me of an episode of *Mouryou no Hako*.

[image: Aoi Bungaku Run! Melos]

[image: Mouryou no Hako]

Notice that it's the same room and painting on the upper right. They are both in Showa era and the protagonists are look-a-like.

Is this related or a real place?

Answer (score 3):

The painting on the upper-right is just a cover for a fictional magazine, 近代文藝 published by 稀譚舎, from the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C5%8Dry%C5%8D_no_Hako).

Apparently, the background art and the music that plays during that scene had been reused and recycled. In fact, if you compare the staff/cast behind *[Mouryou no Hako](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=10153)* and *[Aoi Bungaku](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11096)* (for episode 9–10), you see they have a lot in common:

#### Staff

- **Director: Ryosuke Nakamura**
- **Art Director: Hidetoshi Kaneko**
- Sound Director: Yasunori Honda
- Music: Shusei Murai

#### Cast

- **Tatsumi Sekiguchi/Takada (the protagonists): Hidenobu Kiuchi**
- Yoriko Kusumoto/Melos' Sister: Mikako Takahashi

which explains the protagonists looking and sounding alike, and the recycling of the room design as well as the fictional magazine. However, *[Run, Melos!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run,_Melos!)* has got nothing to do with *Mouryou no Hako*, so the similarities might only confuse people.